# FCE selectorbox element configuration

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

How to add options and values in to the selector box element of Flexible content element(FCE)?
How to use that value in other element's typoscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to add options and values in to the selector box element of Flexible content element(FCE)?

Edit field and click Form link:

[image]

How to use that value in other element's typoscript?

for ex. in other element TS

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = field_2bf3c2
```

where field_2bf3c2 id field name look at image.